# Installing gems in Dockerfile without Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, bundle, bundler

My team hosts our Rails application out of a Dockerfile. We have a few slow gems that are really slowing down our builds. (I'm looking at you`grpc`. )

Is it possible to install a few gems before copying the Gemfile into our Dockerfile? This would allow Docker to cache those build steps, so we don't have to reinstall the slow gems every time the Gemfile changes.

I tried this, but `bundle install` is still installing `grpc`, `sassc` and `nokogiri`.

```
RUN gem install grpc --version 1.28.0
RUN gem install sassc --version 2.2.1
RUN gem install nokogiri --version 1.10.9

WORKDIR /app

ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock .ruby-version /app/
RUN bundle install
```

Comment: `bundle install --deployment` from https://bundler.io/guides/deploying.html#manual-deployment should put you on the right track. Essentially, you compile the gems this way and they're added to `vendor/bundle` and won't have to be recompiled each time.

Comment: Why do you believe that installing them outside of the `bundle install` command will save you time? Also using the `--deployment` and vendor folder wont help - docker layer caching should already take care of it, and should not run this `bundler install` layer,unless anything changed in the Gemfile.

Comment: @DannyB Docker caches each layer of its installation. If I can install them before bringing in the Gemfile, then that layer of the image will be cached on subsequent builds.

Comment: @anothermh Thanks for the reply! I'm not quite sure this solves my problem. The gems that are specifically slow need to be compiled natively, and it seems like your solution would still require a Gemfile.

Comment: I missed the "without Gemfile" part of the title because there's a Gemfile specified in your Dockerfile. And now I'm confused. But the solution seems to be skip your `RUN gem` instructions, use `ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock`, add `RUN bundle install`, _then_ do `ADD /app/`.

Comment: @anothermh Unfortunately, that's not working. When I add the Gemfile, bundler still try to install the gems again.

Comment: If you do it the way I describe then Docker's caching will mean it only happens once.

Comment: @anothermh Am I missing something in your answer? Could you please provide an example of what you mean? Sorry if I'm not understanding.

Comment: I don't have a functional Docker installation at the moment, can't help much more than that which is why I didn't make a proper answer demonstrating it.

Comment: @anothermh I was already adding the app directory after running `bundle install`. I didn't include that in my original question. The problem is any change to the `Gemfile` will trigger a complete rebuild, and they happen often enough to be very disruptive.

Comment: How about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020095/installed-gems-not-found-by-bundler-when-bundle-path-changed-with-docker

Comment: yes you can build your own base image, which contains these gems already. When you want to up the instance use  your local docker image in dockerfile.

Comment: What base image you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about splitting your gemfile, think about the following files.

**slow-gems**

```rb
ruby File.read('.ruby-version').strip

gem 'rubocop'
```

**gemfile**

```rb
ruby File.read('.ruby-version').strip

# add the "slow" gems to the gem-bundle so we do not have to redefine them.
instance_eval File.read('slow-gems')

gem 'flay'
```

**dockerfile**

```
WORKDIR /app

ADD slow-gems slow-gems.lock .ruby-version /app/
RUN bundle install --gemfile=slow-gems

ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/
RUN bundle install
```

This also prevents you from redefining all the gems in the docker image and the gemfile. The only problem you might encounter that the version in both lock-files will drift apart. For now, I don't have a solution for that, but this can also happen while using your current method of adding them to the dockerfile.

The second `bundle install` will re-use the already installed gem from the `slow-gems`-file, this takes less than a second.

**Adition:**
Don't forget to use docker's built-in caching, else this will not be faster and does not help you.

Comment: I really like this solution. I'll test it out tomorrow to see if it works, but it seems like this may be the one for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

***Problem:***

So let's understand the problem first. Whenever you try to spin up your application it takes so much time. I think I understand your problem very well.

1. download gem from internet
2. install and spinup application

***Possible solutions:***

This is a performance of docker files. we have 2 areas which are creating the problems, and 2 different solutions

Solutions:

- Download gem files locally put in a folder and in dockerfile copy those gem files inside the container and then install.
- *Create a base image for your application*. Create a base image from `Ruby`/any other you like and install your `gems` either using the above method:

  1. **copy** `gems` from the local folder and then **paste** inside the `container` 
     or
  2. Use the `RUN` command to install the gems. Whatever you like.

This will be a one time process. With this, you can have your base image which already contains your time-consuming gems installed. Now inside your application `dockerfile` (which is a responsible for the startup the application), you just need to use your own created base image instead of `Ruby` or `Linux` from `Docker Hub`

We will see how to build your own base pre-configured image.
**Let us see step by step.**

Let's follow this GitHub repo: https://github.com/dupinder/docker-ruby-gem-game

Folder Structure (This will help to understand this article)

- application/dockerfile
- gems/download and place local gems
- dockerfile

---

- ***Create a base image and install local gems inside docker container.***

> dockerfile

```
    FROM ruby:latest
    RUN mkdir -p /gems 
    COPY /gems/grpc-1.28.0-universal-darwin.gem /gems/grpc-1.28.0-universal-darwin.gem
    COPY /gems/sassc-2.2.1.gem /gems/sassc-2.2.1.gem
    WORKDIR /gems
    RUN gem install --force --local *.gem
```

Build an image from this dockerfile using follwing command

`docker build --rm -f "dockerfile" -t ruby-gem-base-image:latest "."`

- ***Step 1:***
  I am using the base image as ruby, you can your whatever you want if you are using Linux then in next step you need to install `Ruby`
- ***Step 2:*** Create a folder name gems in the container.
- ***Step 3 & 4:*** Copy the Gems you need to install inside the container from local directory to the directory inside `docker` `container`.
- ***Step 5 & 6:*** Change the working directory to gems, because we want to install gems place inside this directory, So next command is `gem install --force --local *.gem` which help to install gems inside a local directory.

With this, we solved 50% time-consumption. Now docker will never download gems from internet each time and install.

Now let us check is there any of our required gems installed our not. For that:

- Run command `docker images` we will have our newly build image `ruby-gem-base-image`
  [image]
- Run container in detached mode, so that we can `exec` later on `docker run -it -d ruby-gem-base-image`
- Run `docker ps` to get container ID.
- Run `exec` as `bash` inside container `docker exec -it d28234630343  bash`.
- Run `gem list` This will print a list of gems installed, and you will see your required gems there.

[image]

See your gems are installed from local directory.

---

If you follow these steps your problem is resolved. But Now you need if before starting your app docker container already have installed gems.

For this problem, we can use `ruby-gem-base-image` image as our `ruby` application base image. If you remember GitHub repo we have an application directory which has one `dockerfile` if we see that.

```
FROM ruby-gem-base-image:latest
CMD ["gem", "list"]
```

This is your dockerfile which can be used when you want to deploy an application, Use prebuilt docker image which has your gems.
I write the task `gem list` to check is this container have gems from parent image or not.

I think this is a bit clear. Your problem will be resolved with this.

If you need any other help or need help to understand this process, please ask.

---------Dupinder.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Dupinder. However, I'm not sure quite sure that this captures my need. The slow thing I'm trying to prevent is the time it takes to build the docker images. Every time I change a Dockerfile, *all* of the gems have to be reinstalled.

For option 1, I can't install and build the gems locally, and then copy them into the Dockerfile, because the gems that are slow to install are the ones that have to be compiled from source. I run macOS, but the Ruby Docker image is in Linux, so copying compiled images is a no-go.

Comment: For option 1, I could use a base image, but Docker caches each step of the build process for me. If I can just separate the installation of slow gems from the installation of fast gems, and install the slow ones first, then Docker will cache that step the next time I run it. In option 2 above, it looks like you're using `gem install` to install the gems, but I haven't found a way to prevent `bundle install` from reinstalling those same gems. Am I missing something there?

Comment: we should understand that each command in a dockerfile is run in a container resulting from an image created from the previous commands. The images are layered one on top of another.
So there are two things you can do:
1. Look at where changes are happening in your dockerfile. E.g if you have 10 lines in your dockerfile and change is happening at line 2 each time, then the 8 layers following that changed line need to be built each time. You can evaluate if that line 2 can be moved somewhere later in the file (this may or may not be possible).

Comment: 2. Look at creating intermediate images and multiple dockerfiles (or using the multi-stage builds feature). So for example if the first part of your build takes a base OS image and installs a couple of pre-requisites and then layers your app on top of it, you could potentially create an image with the pre-requisites and re-use that without rebuilding all layers for the app part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the options bundle install --deployment or --path to specify a folder where you could install your gems (build a container only for this purpose and then copy the folder outside docker). Then map this directory as a volume in your container, running bundle install after the mapping is done... or *simply copy the folder*:

```
# outside actual image

bundle install --path=vendor/cache

# actual docker image
COPY . /app
COPY vendor/cache /app/vendor/cache
COPY .bundle /app/.bundle 

WORKDIR /app

RUN bundle install --path=vendor/cache
```

The command with --path=vendor/cache generates a bundle config just as this one:

```
---
BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT: "true"
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/cache"
```

As long as your compiled-extension gems versions don't change on your Gemfile, they shouldn't be installed again.

In order to not commit the vendor/cache folder to source-files, you could host it somewhere and have developers download it. I think where you could leave this folder, and how to copy it to the image, is a rather open-ended matter and I'd need more information about your setup to recommend something. Where exactly are you deploying your app in production?

EXAMPLE:

AWS lambda gems with native extensions presents a problem - you might install them inside your OS system but they will not be compatible with the lambda environment.

The approach to make a gem bundle which works is to do the following:

1 - Use **a container to install the gems with native extensions**, in a way that is compatible with lambda:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.7 bundle install --deployment
```

2 - Then, on another container, **you MAP THE GEMS as a volume or copy them, and run your application**

```
docker run --rm --env-file=.env -v $PWD:/var/task:ro,delegated lambci/lambda:ruby2.7 send.lambda_handler
```

I suggest here that you do something similar for your application - use one image to build your platform gems, and then another to run the application, passing these gems to it. **As long as those two images are the same OS, the gems will be compatible.**

A setup similar to this one has worked for my team on a non-docker deployment pipeline, where we pre-install the gems in a folder before pushing a new version and setup bundler to get the gems from it.

Comment: sassc and nokogiri are slow because of the native extensions. 

Would locally building them not cause problems if I use (as example) mac and an `alpine`-image? since this should use the on my mac build extensions with might not work on the `alpine`-image.

Comment: Create a container with the alpine-image, whose sole purpose is to install the gems. Then copy the gem folder locally. That way the gems would be compatible (but not with the mac, probably ^^;). I thought this was self-evident when I said `build a container only for this purpose and then copy the folder outside docker`.


I used the same approach to build nokogiri for AWS Lambda using https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda (the gems installed on my machine didn't work there - like the mac example. But ones installed within these images worked)

Comment: @cesartalves I believe Dennis is right that copying images build from one OS, such as macOS, into another like Linux will not work. My team uses a variety of operating systems, so we need to do something that will work for everyone.

Comment: Your gems will be installed inside a docker container, so they will work if the docker image of the application they're using is the same! I assume everbody is using your application inside a container. I don't possibly know how to make myself clearer: you will install the gems inside a container, then you will NOT use them in your operating system, but in another container with the same base-image as the one were they were created, being compatible by definition.

Comment: I have added the AWS lambda example I dealt with recently in greater detail to my answer. It solves a different problem but I believe the idea can be applied to solve yours